# Comparison of datetime in sql server

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server

I am storing datetime to database as a standard datetime like 2011-10-19 17:18:44.083. I need to select all the rows if the datetime field is equals to 5 days after today. But I dont want this comparison also in time just the day is enough.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.TestBox
where TargetDate = dateadd(day,5, getdate())
```

This is not working, I dont know exactly why but probably its looking at time.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using 2008+, you can cast both as a Date:

```
where convert(date, targetdate) = convert(date, dateadd(day, 5, getdate()))
```

If you're using 2005 or prior, do something like this:

```
where convert(varchar, targetdate, 101) = convert(varchar, dateadd(day, 5, getdate()), 101)
```

Comment: So if I set a stored procedure datetime argument in .NET as DbType.DateTime and the matching parameter in SQL is a datetime, this conversion is required?

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.TestBox
where CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),TargetDate,112) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),dateadd(day,5, getdate()),112)
```

Or, if you have an index on TargetDate:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.TestBox
where TargetDate >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),dateadd(day,5, getdate()),112) 
AND TargetDate < CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),dateadd(day,6, getdate()),112)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select * 
from dbo.TestBox 
where datediff(dd, getdate(), TargetDate) = 5
```

**Sample code:**

```
declare @targetDate as DateTime
set @targetDate = '2011-11-2'
select datediff(dd, getdate(), @targetDate)
```

**Output:**

5

Answer (score 1):

`DATEDIFF` to the rescue!

```
DECLARE @monday DATETIME;
DECLARE @fridayAM DATETIME;
DECLARE @fridayPM DATETIME;
SET @monday = '2011-10-23 10:50:00';
SET @fridayAM = '2011-10-28 08:00:00';
SET @fridayPM = '2011-10-28 17:30:00';
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, @monday, @fridayAm) AS AmDiff, 
       DATEDIFF(DAY, @monday, @fridayPm) AS PmDiff
```

Both AmDiff and PmDiff will be 5.

Answer (score 0):

The following query should do what is required.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.TestBox 
WHERE TargetDate 
        BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, 5, DATEADD(MILLISECOND, 1, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0)))
        AND DATEADD(DAY, 5, DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -2, DATEADD(DAY, datediff(day, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0))) -- between the start and end of the date in 5 days
```

Comment: I recieved a down-vote for this answer, would be helpful to comment on why.

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be due to different date formats.

This link has all the date formatting options in sql http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/what-are-the-valid-styles-for-converting-datetime-to-string.html

Try something like :

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.TestBox where CONVERT(CHAR(8), TargetDate , 1)= dateadd(day,5, (CHAR(8), getdate(), 1))
```

This converts both dates you are comparing to the same format and looses the time part

Instead of using GETDATE() you could also use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP